# Create a variable using document.createElement('a') and apply click on it without appending it to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, download

I am creating an anchor element using jQuery/Javascript. I am using this method:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = '/files/target.pdf';
a.download = true;
```

But how can I perform a **click** event on it **without appending/prepending it to the DOM**? My intention is pretty simple. I want to let the user download a file instead of opening it in browser and that's why I want to avoid the `window.location = '/files/target.pdf';` function.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid setting `window.location`? And what makes you think that triggering a "click" on an `<a>` would not behave precisely the same way?

Comment: Whether the click is triggered in code or you use window.location will make no difference.

Comment: @Pointy Because it opens the file in the browser window and doesn't let the user download it. HTML5 'download' attribute lets an user download file.

Comment: @Phoenix hmm; well that's not in the HTML5 spec. Does any browser other than Firefox implement it? (*edit* oh Chrome too.)

Comment: @Pointy Anchor elements like `<a href="/file/something.png" download>Download Image</a>` lets you download a file. And if you virtually want to change file name using this one sounds great `<a href="/file/something.png" download="Newname.png">Download Image</a>`. These codes work on Firefox, Chrome, Opera etc. But in the case of Firefox, the href attribute must not include link from a different server. The file will be downloded in this cases and without download thag, browser will open that image. This code also works for Audios and Videos. Browser will download them instead of playing.

Comment: point of fact. There is no way to force download :( it always defers to the server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can trigger the "click" like this:

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = 'http://gutfullofbeer.net/mozilla.pdf';
anchor.download = true;

var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

anchor.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

However, when I do that in Firefox, I get a PDF file that's shown in Firefox's built-in PDF viewer. (Chrome seems to do the "right" thing, which is to show a "Save ..." dialog.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Firefox doesn't let users take the advantage of using the `download` attribute if the `href` attribute includes 'http://' to fetch contents from different source/website. If you use `href` like this `/files/file.png` and apply `download` attribute in that anchor Firefox will also show save dialogue box instead of opening it. :)